# Elipsized TextView is returning entire String

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, textview

I've a textView with `maxLine=1` and `ellipsize=end`. I'm trying to get the number of characters on a single line using the following code.

```
        //totalCharacterCount = 538
        val string = "Capture layout hierarchy snapshots Layout Inspector now allows you to save snapshots of your running app’s layout hierarchy, so that you can easily share them with others or refer to them later. Snapshots capture the data you would typically see when using the Layout Inspector, including a detailed 3D rendering of your layout, the component tree of your View, Compose, or hybrid layout, and detailed attributes for each component of your UI. When you want to capture a snapshot, click Export snapshot from the Layout Inspector toolbar. "

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        Handler().postDelayed({

        println("---> text: ${textView.layout.getEllipsisCount(1)} | ${textView.layout.text} | textViewCharactersLength: ${textView.layout.text.length} | totalLength: ${string.length}")
        }, 1000)
```

Layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Capture layout hierarchy snapshots Layout Inspector now allows you to save snapshots of your running app’s layout hierarchy, so that you can easily share them with others or refer to them later. Snapshots capture the data you would typically see when using the Layout Inspector, including a detailed 3D rendering of your layout, the component tree of your View, Compose, or hybrid layout, and detailed attributes for each component of your UI. When you want to capture a snapshot, click Export snapshot from the Layout Inspector toolbar. "
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

The log output I'm getting is

```
---> text: 0 | Capture layout hierarchy sn…﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿ | textViewCharactersLength: 538 | totalLength: 538
```

This is odd cuz the logcat is showing just the visible characters however the count for the characters is equal to the total characters in textView.

**How can I get only the count of visible characters?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok going to answer my own question. We can get the elipsized text like this:

```
val text = textView.text.subSequence(
            0,
            textView.layout.getEllipsisStart(0)
        ) as String
```

Comment: Be careful about casting to String. That will crash if there's any formatting of the text in the TextView, because then `textView.text` is not a String.

Comment: I don't quite follow. What kind of formatting could cause the crash? Would using `.toString()` prevent that?

Comment: Yes that would prevent it. Any formatting of the text within the TextView results in it using Spannable instead of String. That’s why `.text` returns a CharSequence instead of a String (it’s a common interface to both String and Spannable). If it’s a Spannable and you try to cast to String, it will crash.